# How to use a try and except block that kills the script after calling another function?

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, try-except

I am creating a GUI with tkinter, when i click submit i run a function, in the function i need to check that the user has input a number instead of a string. to do this i use the following code:

```
try:
    Thickness = float(Thickness)/1000
except Exception:
    print('Please only enter an integer into the Thickness field')
    Error_Integer_Thickness()
```

Where 'Thickness' is the name of the variable i have retrieved from the GUI input and 'Error_Integer_Thickness' is a function i have created that displays my custom error window.

I want the code to stop after it has found the error, but i dont want to use 'typeError' as then the user wont see my error window. Running this code will generate my error window but from the output i see that the code still tries to continue and fails because of the attempted conversion of a string to a float later on in the code.

I have tried to use 'sys.exit(1)' at the end of the code block but this prevents my error window from being displayed. Additionally using 'sys.exit' isnt ideal because i want the GUI to stay open after closing the error window.

I don't have much experience with try and excpet blocks so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this try, except block inside a function? If so you could just return from the function after the Error_Integer_Thickness() call.

Comment: Yes that's perfect thank you, very nice solution to my problem!